# Base16 theme disable bold

Tags: neovim

I've recently installed Base16 theme and having issues disabling Bold text, I found the customization snippets and have the following in my `.init.vim` (NeoVim) :

```vim
function! s:base16_customize() abort
  call Base16hi("Bold", "", "", "", "", "", "")
endfunction

augroup on_change_colorschema
  autocmd!
  autocmd ColorScheme * call s:base16_customize()
augroup END

colorscheme base16-tomorrow-night
```

I've tried puting the colorscheme line before and after the snipet but none worked, even calling the function doesn't do anything.

Another thing I tried was to highlight the 'Bold' parameter with no sucess:

```vim
hi Bold term=NONE
```

The highlight and the call works if I don't use `termguicolors` but I have it set for better colors.

I also tried to completly disable bold by adding `set t_md=`
proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971581/how-to-disable-bold-font-in-vim#3971805) and also [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_use/cI7ritLRH8Q) but I use the terminal version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the source for `Base16hi(...)`:

```
" Highlighting function
" Optional variables are attributes and guisp
function! g:Base16hi(group, guifg, guibg, ctermfg, ctermbg, ...)
  let l:attr = get(a:, 1, "")
  let l:guisp = get(a:, 2, "")

  if a:guifg != ""
    exec "hi " . a:group . " guifg=#" . a:guifg
  endif
  if a:guibg != ""
    exec "hi " . a:group . " guibg=#" . a:guibg
  endif
  if a:ctermfg != ""
    exec "hi " . a:group . " ctermfg=" . a:ctermfg
  endif
  if a:ctermbg != ""
    exec "hi " . a:group . " ctermbg=" . a:ctermbg
  endif
  if l:attr != ""
    exec "hi " . a:group . " gui=" . l:attr . " cterm=" . l:attr
  endif
  if l:guisp != ""
    exec "hi " . a:group . " guisp=#" . l:guisp
  endif
endfunction
```

You can see that it only executes a `highlight` command when the passed argument is ***not*** `""`. What you want to be passing is `"NONE"`, not `""`. Note that when you set it to `NONE`, any additional attributes will also be reset (underline, italic, etc.)

But, you can't pass `"NONE"` for *every* argument, or you will get an error when it is expecting a color code. Specifically, you want:

```
call Base16hi("Bold", "", "", "", "", "NONE")
```

This will set `gui` and `cterm` to `NONE` instead of bold.

However, directly setting the highlight is better and more portable than relying on a colorscheme's utility function:

```
hi Bold cterm=NONE gui=NONE
```

Other groups might have `gui` or `cterm` set to `bold`, independently of the `Bold` highlight group. In that case, you could do the following:

```
" remove bold
function! s:base16_customize() abort
    " get list of colorschemes
    let l:colorschemes = getcompletion('', 'highlight')

    for c in l:colorschemes
        if synIDattr(synIDtrans(hlID(c)), 'bold')
            exec 'hi ' . c . ' cterm=NONE gui=NONE'
        endif
    endfor
endfunction
```

This will loop through the defined highlight groups, and if it has `bold` set, it will clear it. This may be slow if you have many highlight groups.

Relevant help:

```
:h getcompletion()
:h synIDattr()
:h synIDtrans()
:h hlID()
```

Comment: Tried just that but it doesn't work, also tried to put NONE everywhere doesn't work

Comment: It works for me using `nvim --clean`, then setting colorscheme to `base16-tomorrow-night`, then running `call Base16hi("Bold", "", "", "", "", "NONE")`. Testing against the output of `:so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/hitest.vim`

Comment: How can I reproduce that in my config file so that it's loaded every times ?

Comment: Your `autocmd` works for me, what is the output of `:verbose hi Bold`?

Comment: The output is: 
`Bold xxx cterm=bold gui=bold guisp=#NONE Last set from ~/.config/nvim/init.vim`
I just realized that the style was applied to the terminal version, and I use `set termguicolors`, tried with `hi Bold cterm=NONE gui=NONE term=NONE` with no success. But if I remove `termguicolors` it works. Is there a way to make it work with `termguicolors` ?

Comment: For me `hi Bold cterm=NONE gui=NONE term=NONE` also works, I'm not sure what in your configuration is causing that. I'm going to invite you to a StackExchange chat so we don't pollute the comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113163/discussion-between-ndfg201-and-jake-grossman).